Unknown error , Not able to understand the reason of tx revert
 function executeRent(uint nftId,uint duration) public {
    uint supply =  getTotalSupply();
    require(nftId<=supply,"Property doesn't exists");
    require(tenant[nftId]==msg.sender,"Have to deposit Earnest first");
    require(isInspectionPassed[nftId]==true,"Inspection Isn't passed");
    require(address(this).balance>=priceForRent[nftId],"Insufficient balance");

    address owner = sellers[nftId];
    uint amount = priceForRent[nftId];
    uint rent=calculateRent(duration);
    tenant[nftId]=msg.sender;
    returnTime[nftId]=block.timestamp+duration*1 days;
    rentDuration[msg.sender][nftId] = duration;
    (bool success,)=payable(owner).call{value:amount}("Amount transfered");
    PTKcontract.giveRentTo(msg.sender,nftId);
    activeTokensOnRent.push(nftId);
    require(success,"Transfer Rent to owner failed");
    emit RentedPropertySuccess(nftId,msg.sender,owner,rent);
}

 let transaction = await escrow.connect(signer).executeRent(home.id,duration)
 await transaction.wait()

the transaction is failing with no revert massage.
errors.ts:694 Uncaught (in promise) Error: missing revert data (action="estimateGas", data=null, reason=null, transaction={ "data": "0x60825d5f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001", "from": "0x4bc002D10e53f50442693DCca457EEA202D12Ba2", "to": "0xe05e01f4f8a7b9b18bCb46C52835f739A13827f8" }, invocation=null, revert=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.13.2)

Seems like either the function doesn't exist in the contract instance, or you are sending the wrong data. Can you add more details, like where the contract is deployed and the relevant code.

https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xe05e01f4f8a7b9b18bCb46C52835f739A13827f8#code , here is the contract deployed.

PTKcontract: 0xf95eD1ddff321AF71EF5e53E9722e85784409875
